# (C++) Can the color of text change as it is typed?

Tags: c++, string, input, text, colors

I have a list of instructions in my program and they are activated by entering a string. There are a large number of possible instructions. You could call them commands if you like.

I already have a program that can successfully execute the instructions I've added so far.

For example, adding a person to the database would require the user to enter `add "John" "Doe"`.

This would output to the screen `Added John Doe to the database, ID#1234.` The IDs are random.
I know how to add colors; in this output text, "John Doe" would be colored green.

What I'm wondering is, can I make it so that color changes as one types? Because I learned how to use some kind of keyboard mode change so that when I type a password, all characters are displayed as `*` of any color I desire, or even nothing displayed at all, through "display" of `\0`, and I know how to do that. I was wondering if the color could change before the complete string (extracted with `std::getline(std::cin, str);`) is typed.

The first reason I want the colors to change is because when there are so many commands, and I already have more complex commands than that, I want to provide a way for the user to be able to correct syntax mistakes before they press enter. Something like Windows PowerShell, perhaps, which was written in C#. I know that C# is a very different language than C++, but if C# can achieve something like that, I want to see if C++ can as well. My hope is that it doesn't require thousands of lines of application-specific code, especially considering that PowerShell is an actual application and not a simple terminal-run executable. And while PowerShell appears to be open-source, I don't understand C#. See the bottom for the second reason.

**I have no idea if this is possible, but because similar manipulation of entered text is possible** (as I said, I know how to add colors and also mask text as some other single character like `*`)**, I want to know if this is also possible.**

Simple examples:

Firstly, the user should know when they have not entered a valid command, and when they have. I want the text to be in red until the letters entered so far consist of an actual keyword, like `add`. So, the text would be red until the second `d` is added, when it reverts to white, and if another letter is entered, it becomes red again.

Example 1: `add "John Elias" "Doe"`

After the space, the text after "add" should be red no matter what, unless the character after the space is a quotation mark. In order to tell the user that they have not terminated the string, the text beyond the (orange?) quotation mark should be orange. When the final quotation mark is entered, the entire content of the quotation marks (including the quotation marks) should be some other color (probably green?) to tell the user that they have successfully entered an argument. The same applies to any instances of quotation-mark arguments. Note that a space is allowed in a quotation argument.

Example 2: `list-info 1234`

In this command, it gets more complex. `list` is a separate command, so the text should be red until `t` is entered, and it turns white. But then it turns red again after that, until `o` is entered, and it turns white again. The numerical argument following it should be red if the entered character isn't a digit. If it is, it's still red, because the only valid IDs are 3- or 4-digit numbers. It should turn green(?) once a third digit is entered, and still stay green when another digit is entered. But if a fifth digit is entered (or another character for that matter), the number turns red again. Although this would better be implemented as returning an error if the entered number is invalid, I would still like to know if this can be done as well.

Example 3: `add "John" "Elias" "Doe" "fourth-string"`

Since there is an overloaded function that enables an explicit first-middle-last name to be stored as well, it should be ok if there is a third string. But if there is a fourth string added, then it should be in red no matter what because `add` cannot take more than 3 arguments.

My question is, are any of these things possible? *And yes, I am aware that it is almost certainly better to just implement an error system, but my intention is to expand my coding ability, **and that is the second reason**, and coding an error system will not do that because I have already done that for every command.*

For reference, I'm operating in Linux Ubuntu 18.04, I compile with g++, my code conforms to C++17, I use ANSI escape sequences for color, bold, etc., and for masking characters with something like `*` I use a pointer to a `char` array (passed by address as `char**`) and a C-style `FILE*` to reference the input stream `stdin` (because I haven't bothered to conform it to a typical C++ implementation yet, learning ways to advance my current skills is my priority at this point in time).

Comment: *"as I said, I know how to add colors and also mask text as some other single character like `*`"* Combine both?

Comment: Well the thing is, once you choose a color for the asterisks, it keeps that color until you change it again, meaning that even ordinary text will keep that color until you change it.

Comment: I would use the `curses` library, it's meant for this kind of thing.